# Can I change the brake pads without changing brake disc for the front tyres?

Tags: honda, brakes, car, brake-rotor, brake-pad

I drive Honda Jazz 2010 model.

My brake discs for the rear tyres have experienced some corrosion and I intend to change the brake discs together with brake pads for the rear tyres.

My brake discs for the front tyres are still in good condition, except for the brake pads are 50% worn off as of January 2019 (reported by my garage in annual car service).

My car current mileage is 43000+ miles.

I understand that it is usual to change the brake discs together with brake pads (etc: my rear tyres).

Can I change the brake pads for the front tyres without changing the brake disc?
Will it lead to any damage to my front tyre brake discs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can change the brake pads without changing the disks. Always replace all the pads bearing on a disk (i.e., the pads on both sides of the disk), and to avoid the possibility of different braking force from one side to the other, replace the pads on both front wheels at the same time.

You'll want to make sure that the disks' thickness meets or exceeds the manufacturer's minimum-thickness specifications, as disks do wear and should be replaced when worn to the specified minimum thickness. In addition, inspect the disks carefully: if the disks show cracks or fractures, replace them. The disks' runout should be within specifications. Mild annular wear is not significant.

Comment: You should also check for run-out.

Comment: Where does the myth that rotors must be changed with the disks come from? Is it FUD spread by mechanics to excuse overcharging or was it just some very bad advice that got spread?

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, I forgot that, and (the lack of) runout is important as well. I'll add it to the Answer.

Comment: Oops @SolarMike, I did means rotors and pads, good call.

Comment: @GdD been even better without my typo :) but will delete anyway